# How to sort rows with 3 columns according to the third column's values? by sort , bash

Tags: bash, shell, sorting

I have a tab delimited file with these contents:

```
1   C45874154  22.8221295411     
2   C56931350  -121.889340344   
3   C22240035  NON              
4   C12541514  -232.106357553   
5   C40783672  87.7466539197
```

How can I sort the rows with 3 columns according to the values in third column (from lowest value to the highest in the third column) ?

I know how to do sort for just one column with:

```
sort -n -k 3 file
```

but I don't know how to combine 3 columns together to get an output like this:

```
4  C12541514  -232.106357553
2  C56931350  -121.889340344
1  C45874154  22.8221295411
5  C40783672  87.7466539197
3  C22240035  NON
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: "How can I sort first and second columns according to the values in third column"?? That did not make sense to me.

Comment: Maybe it's better if I change my expression to this: I have values in the third column of each row and I want to sort the rows according to the values in the third column from lowest to the highest. like the sample output. Does it make sense?

Comment: So what's wrong with the `sort` command you know?

Comment: It just works for one column!

Comment: Why should `NON` be the last row?

Comment: cause it is not the numeric value.

Comment: But you are treating it as numeric by using `-n` switch.

Comment: You need general numeric sort. Use the `-g` option for `sort`.

Comment: Aha! in that case NON=0 ?

Answer (score 1):

Try `sort -nk3 -k2,1 aaa`  (I named your example text as `aaa`).  That is, sort first by the third column, numerically.  Then, sort the second and first column, alphabetically.   Makes sense?

```
$ cat -v aaa
1   C45874154  22.8221295411
2   C56931350  -121.889340344
3   C22240035  NON
4   C12541514  -232.106357553
5   C40783672  87.7466539197

$ sort -nk3 -k2,1 aaa
4   C12541514  -232.106357553
2   C56931350  -121.889340344
3   C22240035  NON
1   C45874154  22.8221295411
5   C40783672  87.7466539197
```

Comment: Yes it makes sense. but the problem is how can I add the row with the value "NON" at the bottom as it is not numeric value?

Comment: Great, good to know!  Just in case, I was unaware of the `g` flag, so I was thinking of something like (non-elegant at all) `sort -nk3 aaa | grep -v NON | sort -k2,1 ; grep NON aaa | sort -k2,1`, which gives the exact output you are looking for... useful if your `sort` implementation does not have a `g` flag - just tested in AIX, and there's no `g` flag in here...

Comment: @user3576287: Doesn't `sort -g -k 3 file` place `NON` at top instead of bottom?